# builtin function for string value

Tags: c#

```
strvalues=@"Emp_Name;Emp_ID;23;24;25;26";
```

contains values like this
taking the above string as an input the output should be  like this

```
string strresult=@"23;24;25;26";
```

is there  any  built in function to do like this

thnaks 
prince

Answer (score 3):

Let's add a LINQ solution to the lot...

```
string result = String.Join(";", values.Split(';').Skip(2).ToArray());
```

Or another possibility

```
string result = values.Split(new char[] { ';' }, 3)[2];
```

Both work, but I wouldn't call them elegant either.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] values = strvalues.Split(new char[] { ';' });
```

values will be a string array containing the first column in values[0], second in values[1], etc.

You can use it like this:

```
for (int i = 2, i < values.Length, i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx?ppud=4) class?

```
var strresult = new Regex("([0-9]+;?)*").Match(strvalues).Value;
```

Comment: Of course my snippet isn't perfect. It works just for given string.  However I don't know all the possible requirements as they are not provided in question. I just demonstrated some mechanizm that could help.

Comment: The question was poorly presented. It can be tricky making assumptions with such questions. (that probably explains why the user has such a low accept percentage despite accepting lots of answers - many of his questions are simply of too low quality to generate useful answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
string strresult = strvalues.Replace("Emp_Name;Emp_ID;", "");
```

Comment: I think _Emp_name_ and _Emp_Id_ are not strings, but values different for every employee...

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
string result = String.Join(";", strvalues.Split(';'), 2, 4);
```